# Dose SMTLIB 1.2 has a (get-value) function like like SMTLIB 2

Tags: z3, smt, satisfiability

I wonder if `SMTLIB1.2` has an equivalent to the `SMTLIB2`'s (`get-value`).
I'm running different `SMT` encoding tests using `Z3 SMT solver` and `SMTLIB1.2`, the problem is in the output I keep getting all values the model mixed with 100s of auxiliary variable values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no get-value for SMTLIB 1.2.

SMTLIB 1.2 is deprecated and you can do everything possible 
with SMTLIB 1.2 with 2.0 format instead, so there should be no
real reason to use v1.2 of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm testing an old translator which translates to SMTLIB1.2 that is my reason. Regards, Hani